# how to set up second codeigniter app in subdomain

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain, hosting, cpanel, shared

I have a web app frontend and backend, the frontend was made in codeigniter framework, the backend was also made in another codeigniter framework.

frontend : flum.com 
backend : subdomain.flum.com

the frontend works fine, but i'm having a hard time on the backend, it always shows error 404.

in my shared hosting file manager,

frontend - codeigniter app 1

```
/root/username/application    
/root/username/system    
/root/username/public_html/index.php    
/root/username/public_html/public/(css, js, images folders)
```

backend - codeigniter app 2

```
/root/username/subdomain_application
/root/username/subdomain_system
/root/username/public_html/subdomain/index.php
/root/username/public_html/subdomain/public/(css, js, images folders)
```

both have the same database settings
application/config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'mydatabase',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',...
);
```

frontend application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://flum.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

-I edited the index.php on main ci app

```
$system_path = '/root/username/application';
$application_folder = '/root/username/system';
```

backend application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.flum.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

-I edited the index.php on main ci app

```
$system_path = '/root/username/subdomain_application';
$application_folder = '/root/username/subdomain_system';
```

both have the same .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i expected the backend will be working fine with my frontend app given that backend is in a complete separated codeigniter app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another file structure you can try. Hopefully, it will give better results.

```
/root/username/front/application/
/root/username/front/public_html/index.php
/root/username/front/public_html/.htaccess
/root/username/front/public_html/assets/(css, js, images folders)

/root/username/back/application/
/root/username/back/public_html/index.php
/root/username/back/public_html/.htaccess
/root/username/back/public_html/assets/(css, js, images folders)
```

Both front and back can use the same system directory

```
/root/username/system/
```

Both front and back need their own index.php. The system path is the same in each.

/front/public_html/index.php

```
$system_path = '/root/username/system';
$application_folder = '/root/username/front/application';
```

/back/public_html/index.php

```
$system_path = '/root/username/system';
$application_folder = '/root/username/back/application';
```

A `.htaccess` is needed in both 'public_html' directories, but they are identical to the one you show in the question.

The `$config['base_url']` values you used will be fine in the appropriate config.php files.

Because you use `.htaccess` I assume you're using Apache. The  blocks in the Apache site conf files for both front and back will need the `DocumentRoot` values set to the appropriate public_html directory path.

Database config shown in the question should work for both front and back.

The CodeIgniter documentation has yet another suggestion for [Running Multiple Applications](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html#running-multiple-applications-with-one-codeigniter-installation) that is similar to the structure I show. It uses two index.php files, but at least one of them must have a different name. In your case, perhaps the front uses index.php and the back uses backend.php

To browse to a backend controller named "admin" the URL would be `https://subdomain.flum.com/backend.php/admin`

It would require a more complex `.htaccess` to remove index.php or backend.php from the URL. To be honest, I'm not sure what that looks like and is the reason for the file structure presented.